# Is there a better way to create constants in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Isn't there a better way to create my constants that I can use elsewhere in my code ?

```
export default class AppConstants {
}

Object.defineProperty(AppConstants, 'APP_NAME', { value: 'iVoc'})
/*
*...
*Other constants
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Class syntax should not be used for single instance (static) objects (really class should never be used). Use an `Object` literal and [`freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) it.

```
const AppConstants = Object.freeze({
   NAME : "iVoc",
   VERSION : "0.1B",
});
```